# Laravel - Can I re-use validator instance in the controller?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I use AJAX to send my request, and I want to format errors in special way (still JSON though. I want to change data structure of error and add some flags to it)

So since apparently `$this->validate` just would print out errors without my permission! And I have no control over it, I have to use static method of validator

```
$whitelist = [
    'title'=>'required',
    'slug'=>'present' ,
    'text'=>'present'
];

$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $whitelist);
if($validation->fails())
{
    format_output_likeIwant($validation->messages()->messages());
}

$another_whitelist = [
    'some_other_info'=>'required',
];
```

Just out of curiosity, is there any way for me to validate my `$another_whitelist` with my existing instance? Or should I create a new instance of validator for each list?

By the way, reason for having 2 different validation array is, I'm using this whitelists/arrays to populate my model instance before save/update in database and avoid writing lots of extra code in case of big tables. 2 list here belong to different model/tables ([see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671140/using-2-methods-for-create-update-instead-of-laravel-suggestion-4/38678551#38678551))

I've looked in the laravel documentation, it seems all of the examples assume single validation list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [Validator::after()](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Validator.php#L1858) or [Validator::mergeRules()](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Validator.php#L404). Try it out:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $mainRules = [
        'title'=>'required',
        'slug'=>'present' ,
        'text'=>'present'
    ];

    /** @var \Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validation */
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $mainRules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        //do something
    }

    $additionalRules = [
        'author' => 'required'
    ];
    $validation->mergeRules($additionalRules);

    # validates $mainRules and $additionalRules together...
    dump(($validation->fails()));
}
```

Comment: thanx , i dont know why mergRules is not mentioned in the documentation !

Comment: @max  Yeah I've got used with that. Too many features are hidden.